# MemoryMappedViewAccessor.ReadArray<> throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to read a c-style unicode string from a memory-mapped file and `IndexOutOfRangeException` occurred, so I fixed it by copying char by char but I'd like to use `ReadArray`, which is more readable.

```
MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("some name");
MemoryMappedViewAccessor view = file.CreateViewAccessor();
int len = (int)view.ReadUInt64(0); // Length of string + 1 is stored.
char[] buffer = new char[len];
//view.ReadArray<char>(0, buffer, sizeof(UInt64), len); // EXCEPTION
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) // char by char, works fine.
    buffer[i] = view.ReadChar(sizeof(UInt64) + sizeof(char) * i);
```

Tried to find a short example showing how to use `ReadArray<>` but I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in [`ReadArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267761.aspx), you indicate the desired position with the first parameter, and the offset within the array as the 3rd:

```
public int ReadArray<T>(
    long position,
    T[] array,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

So:

```
view.ReadArray<char>(0, buffer, sizeof(UInt64), len);
```

Is saying to fill the array at indexes from `sizeof(UInt64)` to `sizeof(UInt64) + len - 1` - which will always overflow the usable index values (assuming `sizeof(UInt64)` is greater than 0 :-)).

Try:

```
view.ReadArray<char>(sizeof(UInt64), buffer, 0, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ReadArray, Param 1 and 3 should be swapped.

Intellisense of VS 2010 incorrectly describes ReadArray<>'s parameters.

(may vary with language/locale of VS)

Comment: Just tested in VS2010/.NET 4/English, and the intellisense looks correct to me (although I do have 4.5 installed on this machine as well)

Comment: They may have fixed it for 4.5. They were certainly wrong for 4.0 - see the comments left on the 4.0 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267761%28v=vs.100%29.aspx